# How can i target javascript variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to know how an I target javascript variable using jquery. Here is situation of my web page where I want to use some details that are stored in javascript variable which I will use in user registration. My page codes looks like this

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script>
           var userData =
    {"country":"null","region":"","timezone":"null","key":"sessionSecret","browser":"Chrome","bversion":"0.0","loggedIn":"false"};

        </script>
      </head>
    <body>  
<form id="register">
<button id="regbtn">Register</button>
</form>
    </body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </html>
```

So now how can I use custom jquery function that will target "userData" variable on click of "regbtn"?

I am doing in my custom javascript is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#regbtn').click(function(){
      //do something here that will target that userData variable and will send its data using ajax

      //$ajax function will send data to page with details that user entered and userData 
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to target that userData variable using json. This variable in json data format out put of php. Can anyone help me?

And with negative votes I'd appreciate if you tell me why are you voting negative this question. I am not pro so asked this question. May be this is stupid but not for me. So thank you anyways for seeing this question

Comment: `userData` is global the way you have declared it, you can just use it in your click function, but you really should be handling the `submit` event of your form instead.. regardless, this has been covered many times on SO, just do a search for how to do an AJAX call

Comment: @bruchowski so you want me to write something like <button id="regbtn" onclick="CustomFunc(userData)" >Register</button> like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access your json object "userData", you'll want to add the following in your click function:

```
var country = userData['country'];  
var region = userData['region'];
```

and so on.

You could send the whole object without separation if you plan on sending it via AJAX. Below is an example of this:

```
$(function() {
    var userData = {"country":"null","region":"","timezone":"null","key":"sessionSecret","browser":"Chrome","bversion":"0.0","loggedIn":"false"};
    $('#regbtn').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "someURL",
            data: userData,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // check if response was valid/invalid or do other stuff here 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx for helping me. In my real form, I do have fields. Its just a demo form to show here. I will try to implement as you said.

Comment: it did not help me so I did not mark it. I am sorry

Comment: Revised my answer in hopes to better answer your question.

Comment: This way it works, but if I want to call userdata from javascript file which I am importing from my server, it is not working. I can create userdata in webpage using webserver script and now I need to use the data from external javascript file.

Comment: But I can use like this too. :D thanx.